# Get the variable from the function and concatenation to post the another div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting the alert of firmness,latex and thickness values in separate function.But I have to concatenation of three alert variable and pass to another div class function.concatenation value are post to the other function variables of div class

My Html:

```
   <form id="samplecode" name="samplecode" method="POST" action="">                         
        <div id='div1'>
               <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class='row'>
                  <div class="col-md-7 step-function">
                       <div class="form-group ">
                          <label class="one-step" >Step One:Choose a Support Layer</label>
                       </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class=" fireness-name" >Firmness</label>
                           </div>
                       <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                              <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4  drop-menu">
                                 <select class="form-control"  id="mySelect" name="mySelect" >
                                        <option value="" >select Firmness</option>
                                        <option value="Soft">SOFT</option>
                                        <option value="Hard">HARD</option>
                                        <option value="Thickness">THICKNESS</option>
                                        </select>
                                 </div>
                              <!--  <div class="col-md-1"> <img src='img/hard.jpg'  id="image" class='img-hard' alt=''> </div> -->
                                <div id="Soft" class='col-md-8 value'> 
                                <p> You select Soft.</p>
                              </div>
                              <div id="Hard" class='col-md-8 value'> 
                                <p> You select Hard.</p>
                              </div>
                              <div id="Thickness" class='col-md-8 value'> 
                                <p> You select thickness.</p>
                              </div>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class=" fireness-name" name="dropdown" >Material</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                              <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4  drop-menu">
                                 <label for="imageselect">
                                        <img src="img/latex.jpg" id="image" class="selectimage" alt='' />
                                        <input  id="imageselect" name="imageselect"  type="radio" style="display:none;" value="latex"  />
                                        </label>
                              </div>
                              <div class='col-md-8'>
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class=" fireness-name" name="dropdown" >Thickness</label>
                              </div>
                               <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4  drop-menu">
                                <select class="form-control"  id="Select" name="Select" >
                                        <option value="" >select Thickness</option>
                                        <option value="Thick1">1</option>
                                        <option value="Thick2">2</option>
                                        <option value="Thick3">3</option>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Thick1" class='col-md-8 value'> 
                                    <p> You select Thickness1.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Thick2" class='col-md-8 value'> 
                                    <p> You select Thickness2.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="Thick3" class='col-md-8 value'> 
                                    <p> You select Thickness3.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>

                         <div class='row'>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                 <img class="cust-image-size" src='img/cust.jpg'>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class='col-md-7 anchor'>
                  <div class='pull-right'>
                    <a href='#' id="summer" class='next-color'>Next &#10095&#10095;</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class=' pull-left ' >
                     <a href='#Pre' id="summerpre" class='next-color'><span>&#10094&#10094;</span>Previous </a>
                  </div>
                 </div> 
                </div>
        </form>

              <!--closing first one div class -->

  <!-- Second Comfort Layer container  -->                          



         <div class='container' id='div2'  style="display:none;">
                           <div class="col-md-12" >
                     <div class='row'>
                  <div class="col-md-7 step-function">
                       <div class="form-group ">
                          <label class="one-step" >Step Two:Choose a Comfort Layer</label>
                       </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class=" fireness-name" >Softness</label>
                           </div>
                       <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                               <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4  drop-menu">
                                        <select class="form-control"  id="sel1">
                                            <option style="display:hidden;">select Softness</option>
                                             <option value="Soft">MEDIUM SOFT</option>
                                              <option value="Hard">MEDIUM HARD</option>
                                            <option value="Thickness">MEDIUM THICKNESS</option>
                                        </select>
                                   </div>
                               <div class='col-md-8'> 
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                              </div>
                       </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class=" fireness-name" name="dropdown" >Material</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                              <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4  drop-menu">
                               <img src='img/latex.jpg' alt=''>
                              </div>
                              <div class='col-md-8'>
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label class=" fireness-name" name="dropdown" >Thickness</label>
                              </div>
                               <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                     <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4  drop-menu">
                                        <select class="form-control"  id="sel1">
                                        <option style="display:hidden;">select Thickness</option>
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                        </select>
                                   </div>
                                     <div class='col-md-8'>
                                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                     </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>

                         <div class='row'>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                 <img class="cust-image-size" src='img/cust.jpg'>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                   <div class='col-md-7'>
                          <div class='pull-right anchor'>
                                <a href='#' id='summer2' class='next-color'>Next &#10095&#10095;</a>
                           </div>
                          <div class=' pull-left anchor' >
                              <a href='#Pre' id="summer1" class='next-color'><span>&#10094&#10094;</span>Previous </a>
                          </div>
                     </div>                  
              </div>
```

Jquery:

```
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>         
 <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#summerpre").click(function(){
      $('div[id ^=div]').hide();
     $("#div1").show();
         });
    //div 1 previous
    $("#summer1").click(function(){
   $('div[id ^=div]').hide();
   $("#div1").show();
      });
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
$('#samplecode').validate({
    rules: {
        mySelect: {
            required: true
        },
         Select: {
            required: true
        },
        imageselect:{
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        mySelect: {
            required: 'Please select a Firmness'
        },
     Select: {
            required: 'Please select a Thickness'
        },
        imageselect:{
            required: 'Please select the Image'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(){
    $('div[id ^=div]').hide();
    $("#div2").show();
     return false;
    }
    });
    $("#summer").click(function() {
    $("#samplecode").submit();
    });
    $(function(){
    $('.value').hide();
    $('#mySelect').change(function(){

    $(this).find("option").each(function()
    {
    $('#' + this.value).hide();

    });
    //declare the variable to pass
    var firmness = $(this).val();
     $('#' + this.value).show();
     alert(firmness);
   //I am getting alert here and pass the variable to another function
    });
     });

        var radio = $(this).val();
        $('.selectimage').click(function() {
        var img = $(this).css({border: '4px solid red'});
        $('input').on('change', function() {
      //declare the variable to pass
       var radio=$('input[name="imageselect"]:checked').val();
        var radio =$(this).val();
        alert(radio);
      //I am getting alert here and pass the variable to another function
      //alert the vale fireness        
        });
        });

    $('.value').hide();
    $('#Select').change(function()
    {
    $(this).find("option").each(function()
    {
    $('#' + this.value).hide();
    });
    $('#' + this.value).show();
    //declare the variable to pass
    var Thickness=$(this).val();
    //alert the vale fireness
    alert(Thickness);
 //I am getting alert here and pass the variable to another function
 //I have two concatenation of thee alert in jquery
 });
 });
```

Comment: Hey Vallavan, I've created a jsfiddle of your code, but I'm still not 100% clear on what you're after. Do you mind clarifying?

https://jsfiddle.net/ow6q7283/

Comment: Its not working in jsfiddle. This html jquery is working fine but i am getting alert of firmness,image selection and thickness are in separate separte function but i am not able to concat the alert values ..

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have up to this point into a jsfiddle for me please? That way I'll probably have a better idea of what you're looking for.

Comment: well tanq..I rply soon...